# What is the sum of the series???

Tags: sequences-and-series

What is the sum of this series: $$S(z) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{n^2z^n}$$

I know it diverges to infinity. Does the sum just equal infinity then?

Comment: "*I know it diverges to infinity*" Not in the case that $|z|<1$

Comment: You're right. it converges for |z| < 1

Comment: Hint: for $|z|<1$, we have $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} z^n = 1/(1-z)$. Further, we can differentiate term-by-term.

Comment: Have you seen a proof of why $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty z^n = \dfrac{1}{1-z}$ for $|z|<1$?  One of the ways to find the summation for your series is to consider what happens if you assume you can differentiate formal power series just like you could polynomials.  (*That requires some proof, and it should be surprising that you can... but if that is beyond you for now, you can just take it as fact for the time being*)

Comment: A series isnt a sum, it is a sequence of the $n$th partial sum. If the sequence of the $n$th partial sum diverges the series doesnt equal anything, it simply diverges.

Comment: @CoffeArabica, are you a coffeephile like me to? ☕

Comment: @Cheesecake exactly ;)